# jquery nested form plugin

Tags: jquery, nested-forms

I am looking for a jQuery form plugin that can recive XML or json as an input to dynamiclly generate a nested form.
For example:

```
<root>
<book>
<title>title 1</title>
<price>30</price>
</book>
<book>
<title>title 2</title>
<price>50</price>
</book>
</root>
```

Will be converted to:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="title[0]"/>
<input type="text" name="price[0]"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="title[1]"/>
<input type="text" name="price[1]"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Tmpl (http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)